# How can I show a UIView after take a picture?

Tags: ios, uiview, addsubview

I need to show a UIView after taking a photo (The UIView shows a loading message).

Every time that I need to show a loading message I used this code:

```
NSArray* loading = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LoadingViewController"
                                                     owner:self
                                                   options:nil];

self.loadingView = [ loading objectAtIndex: 0];

[self.view addSubview:self.loadingView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.loadingView];
self.loadingView is the loading UIView.
```

I need to show the UIView loadingView after press "Done" button (after take a photo), I try with this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSArray* loading = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LoadingViewController"
                                                     owner:self
                                                   options:nil];

    self.loadingView = [ loading objectAtIndex: 0];

    [picker.navigationBar addSubview:self.loadingView];
    [picker.navigationBar bringSubviewToFront:self.loadingView];
    /*image processing*/
}
```

But dont work. Also I try changing:

```
[picker.navigationBar addSubview:self.loadingView];
[picker.navigationBar bringSubviewToFront:self.loadingView];
```

with

```
[picker.view addSubview:self.loadingView];
[picker.view bringSubviewToFront:self.loadingView];
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I recomend you to use a library for the loading UIView like [SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD)

Also You need to use Threads for what you are trying to do, take a look at [this link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1888/how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-tutorial-part-33)